# Difference between these two jquery statements related to checkbox values

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Can anyone tell me the difference between:

```
if($('.activity-type-check').is(':checked'))
type = $('.activity-type-check').val();
```

And

```
type = $('.activity-type-check:checked').val();
```

Comment: There is no difference between above two statements. But for best practices one can use `type = $('.activity-type-check:checked').val();`. as condition will automatically handled by jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:checked will select all elements which are checked.
In the first snippet you have condition to check if an element is checked whereas $('.activity-type-check:checked') returns all elements of class activity-type-check and are checked.